# iOS - NSString with Hash # and Star * reversed when localized

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, nsstring

An example will illustrate the problem.

Consider the code: *678*0123456789*45#. If I used this code *inside* any left-to-right language, the code appears correctly (in an alert view message).

But If I used this code *inside* any right-to-left language, the code is messed up. It is not reversed but rather appears like that #45*0123456789*678*. As you can see, the code is *not* reversed as the numbers betweens the stars and hashes are correct. The whole code however is reversed. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: You want to insert left-to-right embedding and pop-directional-formatting markers in your phone number to mark it up as needing explicit writing direction. [This page](http://www.iamcal.com/understanding-bidirectional-text/) has a nice explanation for this. Your string should end up something like @"\u202A*678*0123456789*45#\u202C" (i.e. wedged in between the LTR character 202A and the PDF character 202C).

Comment: yes, this is the answer. I will check the link to get the big picture. Thank you. Please, repost it as an "answer" so I can check it.